# Spark can't connect to Hive metastore (NoSuchTableException)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie, que

I wrote this code, and run in a cluster with spark-submit: SUCCESS

When I tray do this in Job (QUE)

```
[Create Job][https://yadi.sk/i/GyOIRRsv_jVs-Q]
```

I catch error NoSuchTableException:

```
2018-12-04 12:48:19,244 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0-cdh5.15.1

2018-12-04 12:48:19,408 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, null
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException

I think it's happened because I don't have to connect to Hive MetaStore.

Then I added:

```
hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://***.***.***.***:9083")
```

and still, catch error...

I use:

- Claudera CDN 5.15.1
- Spark 1.6.0
- Scala 2.10.6
- QUE

Code

```
package ShowCase

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SaveMode}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext


object TotalCalls {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Program")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    hiveContext.setConf("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://***.***.***.***:9083")
    val source = hiveContext.table("cdr.subs_cdr_nrm")
    import hiveContext.implicits._

    val result = {
      source.filter("call_type = 1 or call_type = 2 or call_type = 29 or call_type = 43")
        .select(from_unixtime(((floor(unix_timestamp($"start_time") / 900)) * 900), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").as("interval"), $"cellid", $"duration")
        .groupBy("interval", "cellid")
        .agg(count("*").as("total_calls"))
    }

    result.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("cdr.call_result")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

Comment: Try going through beeline/hive cli with the same user you run the spark job and see if you are able to see the table and query it.